# Translate or Scale Coordinates from Image to Coodinate system

Tags: math, formula

I'm creating a system where a user clicks on an image on a webpage that is generated from a CAD program. The image is of a cad drawing. I want to translate the coordinate of the image click to the real system coordinates.

The image changes sizes depends on CAD window size. I can get the bounding coordinates of the CAD system, and I can extract the coordinate that is clicked on the image as well as it's size.

How do I correlate the image coordinate to the real coordinate?

For example my bounding box of the CAD system is ll(2029 3350) ur(2373 3489). My image is 1024 X 415. My clicked image coordinate is 442 332. How do I translate that to the CAD coordinate system? I feel like this should be simple, but I'm really struggling.

I tried:
        `xFactor = (urx - llx)/w
        yFactor = (ury - lly)/h
        destX = xFactor * x
        destY = yFactor * y`

But it's not even close to correct. Maybe I need to calculate shift as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing the shift. Adding the minx and miny of the window bounding box gets me my correct coordinate.